# Externalize pgfpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, matplotlib

When I do

```
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetfigurename{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and compile my LaTeX file with `pdflatex --shell-escape`, a file `foo0.pdf` is created the first time and that PDFfile is just included from then on.

However, the same doesn't work for `pgfpicture`s.  I'm creating figures using `matplotlib` (which rocks, btw.) and they're plain PGF.  When I include those, they are compiled every time, which is pretty time consuming.

I didn't find any way to include a `pgfpicture` in a `tikzpicture`.  When I tried simply to do something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfpicture}
    ...
    \end{pgfpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got "TeX capacity exceeded" errors.

Comment: A `tikzpicture` is a special form of a `pgfpicture`, so you can't use the one inside the other. Note that there is also the `standalone` bundle which allows to compile picture environments or any other LaTeX material just once and automatically include the resulting PDF then. However, it works the other way around: the pictures are supposed to be inside a file of its own with an own preamble.

Comment: `\tikzexternalize` works only for `tikz` pictures. Externalization support for `pgfpictures` is somewhat more low-level than for `tikzpictures` (which makes perfect sense, since `pgf` itself is more low-level than `tikz`). I suggest you read about externalizing `pgf` graphics in section 80 (Externalizing Graphics, under VII The Basic Layer) of the PGF manual.

Comment: Thanks.  I've read that part of the manual and I've got it working for one graphic.  If I have graphics `graphic1` and `graphic2` and I do `pdflatex --jobname graphic1 mydoc.tex`, I get "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file graphic2): unknown type of image" and vice-versa.

Comment: I assume you are using `matplotlib`'s PGF backend. You could try [matplotlib2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz) instead, which converts to tikz. Depending on what you are doing, you might be interested in my [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package, which can also be used to cache matplotlib figures (and can create them in parallel, if your processor has multiple cores).

Comment: Can I say that this question is exactly what I need too and I feel it shouldn't be closed as too localised? It would be of great benefit to me to find an answer to this! Please reopen

Comment: I suspect (although I cannot be sure) that this was closed as it lacks details, _e.g._ a MWE. Historically this tended to be 'to localized' but perhaps now would be 'unclear'. In any case, anyone interested in the same issue is advised to open a new question will a full example.

Comment: I have opened a new question concerning this problem that includes a MWE and some additional details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633872/tikz-externalizing-a-pgf-image-e-g-from-matplotlib